# Remove Lubuntu and LXDE from the flavour menu at log in

Tags: uninstall

How can I remove Lubuntu and its counterpart on the log in part where they can be seen (flavour drop down menu). I ran `sudo apt-get --purge remove lubuntu-desktop`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open */usr/share/xsessions* and remove the corresponding *.desktop entries. You'll need to use elevated privileges to do so.

When I login and click on the various log-in options, I see this (on my system):

[image: Login options]

Now, I open my terminal and execute the following commands to prevent *jwm.desktop* from appearing in the log-in options:

[image: Image of terminal route]

Details:

- After opening the terminal, I type `cd /usr/share/xsessions` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Doing so takes me to the folder which stores information on what appears in the login options. You can see that I have *Jwm*, *Lubuntu*, *Openbox*, *Xfce Session* and *Xubuntu Session*.
- Suppose I don't wish to see *Jwm*. I can "hide" *jwm.desktop* by using the `mv` command: `sudo mv jwm.desktop jwm.desktop.bak`
- `sudo` is necessary because I'm not the owner of the files in */usr/share/sessions*. Using `sudo` means that you're using "elevated privileges".
- Then I close the terminal, log out and log back in. The *Jwm* option is no longer visible. If I want it back I can use the same process in reverse: `sudo mv jwm.desktop.bak jwm.desktop`

Of course, if you're absolutely sure you never want to see, for example, the *Jwm* entry again, you could use `sudo rm jwm.desktop`. Depending on what you want to remove, change *jwm.desktop* to the appropriate one.

[image: Jwm option is removed]

Comment: what is elevated privileges

Comment: how can I remove it i can't toggle the remove button

Comment: can you just help me on how can I reinstall Xubuntu so I can start new

Comment: I want stick to Xubuntu because earlier I was confused on what should I choose. If I reinstall Xubuntu, I can get  more space. Sorry if I ask too many questions.

Comment: Are you running out of space? You won't really gain a lot of space by removing the components Lubuntu pulled in.

Comment: But if you're interested, we ca provide a list of some relatively "big" applications that Lubuntu has and which you can  safely remove :)

Comment: But is there any way to reset Xubuntu to its original state after installation?

Comment: No, there's no easy way. For a newcomer, a reinstallation would be the easiest way.